# Bash for loop, using grep

Tags: bash, grep, for

I have a folder full of zipped files, I would like to have these files piped to a second bash script containing commands for programs to be run on them using a for loop. So far I have:

```
targ_path='/scratch/mine/allfiles/targetfiles/'
mybashpath='/scratch/mine/secondbash.sh'
cd $targ_path                                               
ls | grep \.gz | $mybashpath {}
```

But I understand this is wrong, and I need to use a for loop to send piped files to my second bash script.

Im very new to bash and I'd greatly appreciate some assistance here.

Comment: You want to pipe the file _names_, right, not the file _contents_? What does `secondbash.sh` do? The details will depend on what kind of input that script expects.

Comment: @terdon The second script uses a package of programs written as a single perl script. 

`#!/bin/bash
file=$1
unzip_path='/scratch/mine/unzipped'
subj_targ_path=${targ_path}/${file}
zcat $subj_targ_path > $unzip_path

myperscript.pl $unzip_path`

Comment: Please don't use comments to provide extra information. As you can see, formatting is less useful in a comment. Instead, update your question so that everyone can easily see all your information in one place

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your intention is to change directory to `$targ_path` and then call your `$mybashpath` script once with each file that has a name ending in `.gz` in that directory as argument.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

targ_path=/scratch/mine/allfiles/targetfiles
mybashpath=/scratch/mine/secondbash.sh

cd "$targ_path" || exit

for name in ./*.gz; do
   "$mybashpath" "$name"
done
```

This changes the directory to `$targ_path`, but exits if that fails.

It then iterates with a loop over the names matching the globbing pattern `./*.gz`, i.e. each name in the current directory ending in `.gz`. It uses these names as arguments to your `$mybashpath` script, calling the script once for each name.

I also set the `nullglob` shell option at the top of the script to stop the loop from running a single time if the globbing pattern  doesn't match anything.

Depending on how the `$mybashpath` script uses the argument, the `cd` may be unnecessary:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

targ_path=/scratch/mine/allfiles/targetfiles
mybashpath=/scratch/mine/secondbash.sh

for name in "$targ_path"/*.gz; do
   "$mybashpath" "$name"
done
```

Comment: @Kusalanada I dont seem to be getting any output. I removed the nullglob line as I know that matching does happen, and i think it was interfering with my job submission.  I you see my comment to  terdon, it details what the second script is doing. Why do I not need curly brackets in your for loop? Is there a way to use | to pipe things from the for loop to my second script?

Comment: @Zoidberg_OuuuO Leave the `nullglob` option in place. You only need curly braces in a small number of instances, `${a}` is the same as `$a`. If your comment to terdon is important, it should be part of your question, not a comment.